# How use Power BI API REST with python?

Tags: python, powerbi

I'm new to this world of BI. I'm trying to make a request through the BI REST API. I want to get certain set of data that is in my workspace. I'm having problems when making the request. Could you please let me know if I'm missing any parameters?

I want to be able to get the dataset from my BI workspace.

Below the code:

!pip install adal

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
import adal

authority_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common'
resource_url = 'GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets'
client_id = 'workspace_ID'
username = 'BI_email'
password = 'BI_password'

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority=authority_url,
                                 validate_authority=True,
                                 api_version=None)

token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(resource=resource_url,
                                                 client_id=client_id,
                                                 username=username,
                                                 password=password)``
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see above, it looks like you've already taken the first step to acquire a bearer token. To interact with the Power BI Rest API you'll need to attach this bearer token to each request.

The easiest way to do this is with requests and a `Session`.

```py
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({"Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"})

dataset_id = "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229"
r = session.get(f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{dataset_id}")
dataset= r.json()
```

Alternatively, you could try the [`pbipy`](https://pypi.org/project/pbipy/) library which was made to simplify the above.

```py
from pbipy import PowerBI

pbi = PowerBI("your bearer token")
dataset = pbi.dataset("cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229")
```

Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of this library. It's in early development, so feel free to pass on any feedback on the github site.